# Origin of dead giveaway

Tags: etymology, idioms

I was answering a question at ELL and used the phrase "dead giveaway" and thought that it might not be clear to a non-native speaker. This thought lead me to wonder, where did we get that phrase. I searched a little on Google, but did not find an answer.

Comment: http://www.phrases.org.uk/bulletin_board/56/messages/494.html The trick to limiting Google searches to the origins of words and phrases is to use the word "etymology" as one of the search keywords.

Comment: @MMετάEd Why not put that as an answer, so that it can be accepted (if the OP so chooses), rather than leave an ever-open question as complained of at [http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/3965/unanswered-questions-are-stacking-up?cb=1](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/3965/unanswered-questions-are-stacking-up?cb=1)?

Comment: Thanks @MετάEd I had kind of reasoned that out myself, but wanted a reference as well. If you'll post here, your own version of the answer found at that link, I'll accept it. I appreciate you not wanting to just put a link as an actual "answer".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://www.phrases.org.uk/bulletin_board/56/messages/494.html:

> "Giveaway" in the sense "inadvertent betrayal or revelation; something that gives [the game] away" is US slang dating from 1882. "Dead" has here the sense "absolute, sure", which was used in many phrases coined around that time - e.g. dead ringer, dead centre, dead earnest, dead certainty. (VSD)

Comment: Would you have answered if OP had simply asked about the origin of "giveaway"? I think that part is General Reference, and the "dead" part is a Duplicate.

Comment: Frankly, I do not understand your question.  Did I do something wrong or inappropriate?

Comment: I'd closevoted the question 5-10 minutes before you answered. I didn't see why you posted an answer to what just looked like a duplicate to me, so I'm asking whether you genuinely think that "origin of *giveaway*" is a valid question here.

Comment: @FumbleFingers:  Sorry; my bad (as the young people say).  I wasn't conscious of your posting until just now.  In other words, I wasn't dissing you (again, as the young people say--at least today).

Comment: I assume that means you wouldn't have. Actually, I'd assumed (mistakenly) that you could have closevoted as a dup - but I just checked [privileges](http://english.stackexchange.com/privileges) and realised you couldn't have, even if you'd wanted to. But I expect you'll get there soon enough. There's only one other closevote as I write, though, so maybe others *do* see "origin of *giveaway*" as a valid question for ELU. But I'm afraid I don't.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, If we beging saying that since part of an answer has already been answered, and the other part is general reference, we'll end up with a lot more closed questions. Not every case like this will break down so easily into "What do these two words mean individually".

Comment: @TecBrat: Well, we'll never be able to find out now what would have happened if you'd just asked for *origin of "giveaway"*. I know I said General Reference above, but if that was the *only* question, and someone else had already voted Not Constructive, I'd have gone with that. All you're likely to get for such trivial metaphoric usages is "first recorded use in print", which may be very much later than "first spoken usage". And I can't see that it really needs any "explanation", given that *give away the truth* occurs much earlier.

Comment: I just got a "Notable Question" badge for this, and coming back to it, I should clarify that what I was looking for really had much less to do with _giveaway_ and more to do with this metaphoric use of _dead_ and comes down to, I think, this quote from the most upvoted but not accepted answer on the dupe target. _I would guess the following: death -> permanence -> absoluteness. But this is all speculation_